# FileReader not working in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, filereader

I have multiple images on a page. I want to send image data to my server-side code from the client side. On calling `createCategoryTemplate` method I get the empty value of `this.CategoryList` and `categoryDetails.image` is also empty.

```
save(): void {
var fileByteArray = '';
var Image;
let j: any;
this.CategoryList = [];
for (j = 0; j < this.form.value.addresses.length; j++) {
    Image = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(j));

    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
        var imageData = fileReader.result;
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(imageData);
        for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
            fileByteArray += (String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]));
        }

        let categoryDetails = new CategoryDto();
        categoryDetails.categoryName = this.form.value.addresses[j].categoryName;
        categoryDetails.image = btoa(fileByteArray);
        this.CategoryList.push(categoryDetails);
    }

    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(Image.files[0]);

}

this._categoryservice.createCategoryTemplate(this.CategoryList).subscribe((result) => {
    this.notify.info(this.l('SavedSuccessfully'));
});

}
```

When I run the client side code line by line using the breakpoint, it works as expected.

I think the reason behind the unexpected result could be that `onload` gets called by `readAsArrayBuffer` completed and `createCategoryTemplate` gets called immediately after `readAsArrayBuffer`.

But I'm not able to solve it, please help.